# LINQ to xml - how do I select a particular node?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

I have this xml. How do I select a `<region>` depending upon the "section"?

```
<PhoneAndAddresses>
  <PageTitle></PageTitle>
  <region section="CityServices">
    <Business>
      <Name>
        Atlanta Police Department
        <Name>
          <Address>612 Magnolia St NW, Atlanta, GA 30314</Address>
          <Phone>404-658-6486</Phone>
        </Business>
    <Business>
      <Name>Atlanta Police Department</Name>
      <Address>398 Centennial Olympic Park Dr NW, Atlanta, GA 30313</Address>
      <Phone>404-658-6636</Phone>
    </Business>
  </region>
  <region section="Hospitals">
    <Business>
      <Name>
        Emory University Hospital
        <Name>
          <Address>612 Magnolia St NW, Atlanta, GA 30314</Address>
          <Phone>404-658-6486</Phone>
        </Business>
    <Business>
      <Name>
        St Joseph's Hospital
        <Name>
          <Address>398 Centennial Olympic Park Dr NW, Atlanta, GA 30313</Address>
          <Phone>404-658-6636</Phone>
        </Business>
  </region>
</PhoneAndAddresses>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (untested):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmltext);
var selectedRegion = doc.Root.Descendents("region").FirstOrDefault(r => r.Attribute("section").Value == "target value");
```

Comment: I am getting null. I  want to get <Business>
      <Name>
        Atlanta Police Department
        <Name>
          <Address>612 Magnolia St NW, Atlanta, GA 30314</Address>
          <Phone>404-658-6486</Phone>
        </Business>
    <Business>
      <Name>Atlanta Police Department</Name>
      <Address>398 Centennial Olympic Park Dr NW, Atlanta, GA 30313</Address>
      <Phone>404-658-6636</Phone>
    </Business>

Comment: Add .Value to the end of r.Attribute("section").  Attribute() returns an XAttribute, which will never == "string value"

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(input).Descendants("region")
    .FirstOrDefault(e => (string)e.Attribute("section") == "CityServices");
```

or using XPath:

```
//region[@section = 'CityServices']
```

Comment: I am getting null. I  want to get <Business>
      < Name>Atlanta Police Department</Name>
          < Address>612 Magnolia St NW, Atlanta, GA 30314</Address>
          < Phone>404-658-6486</Phone>
        < /Business>
    < Business>
      < Name>Atlanta Police Department</Name>
      < Address>398 Centennial Olympic Park Dr NW, Atlanta, GA 30313</Address>
      < Phone>404-658-6636</Phone>
    < /Business>

Comment: Thanks Kirill I got it working. I am not sure how to format an xml when asking a question or adding a comment.

Comment: I had to add the .Value attribute like @dthorpe mentioned to get it working. Thanks

Comment: @Mithil, Also I suggest to use my code, because code provided by @dthorpe can raise  NullReference exception in case `region` element doesn't contain `section` attribute.